# How to prevent user login automatically after registration in Laravel 5.5

Tags: authentication, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

Im using laravel 5.5 and the auth module that provides login and registration modules automatically.

But when i register a new user, it automatically logs in the user and shows the home page.

I dont want to login the user. How do i prevent this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to overwrite the `register()` function in `/app/Http/Controllers/Auth/RegisterController.php` file

This is the original function:

```
public function register(Request $request)
{
    $this->validator($request->all())->validate();

    event(new Registered($user = $this->create($request->all())));

    $this->guard()->login($user); // this line logs in the user

    return $this->registered($request, $user)
                    ?: redirect($this->redirectPath());
}
```

and you need to copy this function into RegisterController.php and customize it however you want.

Comment: im getting this error: Class App\Http\Controllers\Auth\Request does not exist.

Comment: You just need to import it on top. Find in some other controllers the correct path. I am currently away from keyboard. I will update my answer as soon as I get to my laptop.

Comment: ok thnx its working.  Just want to ask where is the actual register function defined and is overwritting it in this way not cause any other issue in the future ?

Comment: That function is in a trait `RegistersUsers` under `/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/RegistersUsers.php`